# SQS Size growing even though messages deleted is equal to messages received

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

What can be the reason for number of messages in a SQS queue increasing if the number of messaged deleted is equal to number of messages received?

Comment: Could you tell us more about how you process messages in the queue? Are you using an AWS Lambda function, or a fleet of workers? Feel free to edit your question to add these details.

Comment: I think I kind of know answer to this. Is this right to say that number of messages received is actually the messages received by the workers or lambda which is listening to queue. I was originally thinking it as a messages received to SQS. Now, I observed that messages received by SQS queue is actually represented by Messages sent. Is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Available CloudWatch Metrics for Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html):

- `NumberOfMessagesDeleted:` Amazon SQS emits the `NumberOfMessagesDeleted` metric for every successful deletion operation that uses a valid receipt handle, including duplicate deletions.
- `NumberOfMessagesReceived:` The number of messages returned by calls to the `ReceiveMessage` action.
- `NumberOfMessagesSent:` The number of messages added to a queue.

Or, in simple terms:

- **Sent** means sent to the queue
- **Received** means retrieved from the queue
- **Deleted** means removed from the queue